# Create dialog in windows services at vista+ system

Tags: c++, winforms

I use  `CreateDialogParam` to create a dialog in my service, it can run normally in XP system.But when I put it into Vista or Win7, it doesn't work. I want to know why or what else APIs I can use?

Comment: Why not just separate the UI of your application from the part that runs as a service? Then your UI can display dialog boxes all it wants. This is the approach taken by most commercial software packages.

Comment: But the project is someone left over. I should fix the BUG soon, so it is no time. Is someone else meet this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With session 0 isolation introduced in Vista, services cannot show UI since they run in a separate, non-interactive session. You need to run a standard app on the interactive desktop and use an IPC mechanism to communicate with the service in order to show UI on behalf of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Read Microsoft's documentation about the changes made to services in Vista.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480152.aspx#appcomp_topic12

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx